# How to color label on focusing input box via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want the effect of coloring label on input focus. Like when i focus input box, the label color should change to blue. But this is not working and I want to know why as well as how to fix this?

```css
.test-label{
   color: purple;
}
.test-box:focus .test-label{
   color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class = "test-label">Label</label>
  <br />
  <input type = "text" class = "test-box">
 </form>
```

Comment: two selectors separated by space means they would be nested, but your label and input are not nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just keep `label` after `input` and apply [General Sibling
>   Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp), and make label `position:absolute` to keep `label` position on top

```
.myInput:focus~label {
  color: blue !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
.test-label {
  color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.test-box {
  position: relative;
}

.myInput:focus~label {
  color: blue !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myInput:hover {
  color: blue !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form class="test-box">

  <br />
  <input type="text" class="myInput">
  <label class="test-label">Label</label>
</form>
```

*and this will run on all modern browsers*. Hope this will help you.

Comment: No Problem, Tricky thing is always better ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) for this.

[Note it has limited support.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

```css
.test-label {
  color: purple;
}

form:focus-within .test-label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="test-label">Label</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" class="test-box">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your `input` inside the `label` and use [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) (note: doesn't currently work in IE or Edge browsers)

```css
.test-label {
  color: purple;
}

.test-label:focus-within {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="test-label">Label
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="test-box">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra selector from ".test-box:focus" .

```css
.test-label{
   color: purple;
}
.test-box:focus {
   background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class = "test-label">Label</label>
  <br />
  <input type = "text" class = "test-box">
 </form>
```

Comment: No i want text color to be changed!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test-label{
   color: purple;
}
.test-box:hover .test-label{
   color: blue !important;
            cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form class="test-box">
  <label class = "test-label">Label</label>
  <br />
  <input type = "text">
 </form>
```

Comment: I want on focus dude.